# What to do about this property of unknown ownership I had

Tags: halal-haram, property

Two years ago I received a gift of a PlayStation 5 from my brother. Along with this gift came 10 games which were identical. My brother said the person must have forgotten to take them out from the PS5 box. The PS5 was shipped and  must have been packed from another city. Not wanting to do anything with them I stayed away from them.

As time passed my brother put them in my room. Later on when time passed I thought and convinced myself that they must have been a gift since the package of the box was made in a way that they had to be placed in a very precise and deliberate manner for them to fit in the box. Plus the person never called to ask for them back. I still don't know whether they were a gift or not since they were very noticeable and had to be placed deliberately in the PS5 box when we were sold the unit.

At that time I did not know the rules of stolen or lost  property and when I asked my local ulma and parents they said it must have been a gift  and still do. So later I sold four games thinking were probably a gift. Now as time passed and I read the rules of lost and stolen property I replaced the games I sold and asked my brother to tell me the number of the person who sold him the PS5. But he doesn't remember the person's name or the exact place of the shop. He did tell me he searched for it for the number and doesn't remember the person's name. He also wants to sell the games and doesn't want me to return them since he bought the PS5 and that they are his property. Now what do I do about this?

1. I sold three of the games to a person who sells games on the other side of my country. I contacted him and his uncle sold them from his shop and the other I will get back. Or is my replacing the games with my games to reimburse the price enough?
2. Should I make announcements or make call to every single store in the city from which they were bought from? It's the second largest city in the country and the person that sold it to us might not even remember since its been two years and I don't have enough money to make such announcements. I am young and don't have the time or resources to do this.
3. Is making announcements allowed online and after 2 years? I highly doubt anyone would claim them or remember them. Is an announcement even necessary since I don't know whether they are even lost or not?
4. Are the games even stolen since they came in a box from a transaction and were never asked to be returned?
5. What do i do now that my brother wants to sell them and doesn't want to return them and views them as his property since he bought the PS5 and they might genuinely be  a gift, and he never directly gave their responsibility to me and only asked me to sell them, thus I can't even give it to charity and can't return it if by chance I do manage to find the guy which I don't know how I'll do that.
   Currently the games are with my brother with the ones i placed to replace the ones I sold. What should I do? Please help me with this issue that has been plaguing me for so long.